# Express & Node: CORS fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have a Express and Node backend API written for my Angular 2 front end.

I get this common error when CORS is not set up properly in the entry file for the server:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://keilcarpenter-portfolioapi.herokuapp.com/api/sendemail. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://keilcarpenter.co.nz' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503..

Here is the http POST request from the client:

```
sendEmail(queryObject: any) {
  const body = JSON.stringify(queryObject);
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post('https://keilcarpenter-portfolioapi.herokuapp.com/api/sendemail', body, {headers: headers})
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

The error implies that I am passing a preflight request but its only a POST request and from my understanding a request is only preflighted if it is any other than a GET, POST or HEAD request which is confirmed in this [HTTP Access Control documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

I am positive I have set my CORS headers up properly according to [enable-cors.org](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

```
// Get dependencies
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Get our API routes
var api = require('./server/routes/api');
var app = express();
// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);
/**
 * Create HTTP segggrver.
 */
var server = http.createServer(app);
/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, function () { return console.log("API running on localhost:" + port); });
//# sourceMappingURL=server
```

**Questions**

- Why is the error saying that the request is preflighted when it is a POST?
- Why is my CORS headers not being accepted?

Comment: use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 2):

The request gets preflighted due to `headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')`

> The error implies that I am passing a preflight request but its only a POST request and from my understanding a request is only preflighted if it is any other than a GET, POST or HEAD request which is confirmed in this [HTTP Access Control documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

See the part of those same docs that says this:

> If the Content-Type header has a value other than the following:
>
> - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
> - `multipart/form-data`
> - `text/plain`

And you need to ensure your express code handles the `OPTIONS` request in the right way. For help with that, see the answer at [CORS with Express.js and Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613352/cors-with-express-js-and-angular2/42613471#42613471) or as suggested in a comment above, just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors, which takes care all this stuff for you.